# What is an alternative to the TabControl.ControlRemoved event?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've got a TabControl where I'm listening for the ControlRemoved event and then make a change to a MenuStrip item upon TabControl.TabCount equaling zero.

What I've found is that the TabCount doesn't update until this Event method has completed which, to me, make the name of the event misleading.

Any ideas on an alternative to this event?

Comment: There isn't anything misleading: the `ControlRemoved` event is fired when the control is removed, not when the `TabCount` property is updated to match. (Don't get me wrong, I do understand why this is a problem for you.)

Comment: As for a fix, it depends, is it possible for you to create a derived class from `TabControl`, or are you stuck using exactly the `TabControl` control?

Comment: If you remove a tab at a time can't you just check for TabCount - 1 == 0.

Comment: Should be relatively easy to add an internal variable to keep tracks of the tabPages added or removed in your app. Use that var to update your menustrip.

Comment: @hvd, Yes, I can create a new class. To your first comment, the ControlAdded updates the TabCount prior to the method firing which, to me, is inconsistent.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu, That appears to work for my needs, ty.

Comment: I've explained a bit more in my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu Would you post your suggestion as the answer?  I'd like to close out this question and would like you to get credit for helping me.

Comment: @Josh Posted as an answer now. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove a tab at a time you can simply check for:

```
TabCount - 1 == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

A posibility would be to check if the number of Controls is 1. If so the last tabpage is about to be removed. (You can even check which one using the EventArgs: `e.Control`)

I tested overriding the OnControlRemoved but it suffers the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possibility that the `TabControl` updates its `TabCount` property by subscribing to its own `ControlRemoved` event. This isn't really the case, but it helps (I think) to understand the problem. The `TabControl`'s own `ControlRemoved` handler may run after yours. What you need is an event that runs *after* the `ControlRemoved` event.

What `TabControl` does is create a derived class of the standard `ControlCollection` class, namely [TabControl.ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.controlcollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). What you can do is derive from *that*, and override the `Add` and/or `Remove` methods. Call `base.Add(control)` / `base.Remove(control)`, and then raise a custom event. Use that custom event instead of `ControlAdded`/`ControlRemoved`.

*Edit*: untested right now, will test when I can, but it should be something like

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    public event ControlEventHandler TabAdded;

    public event ControlEventHandler TabRemoved;

    protected override Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
    {
        return new ControlCollection(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnTabAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var @event = TabAdded;
        if (@event != null)
            @event.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnTabRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var @event = TabRemoved;
        if (@event != null)
            @event.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    public new class ControlCollection : TabControl.ControlCollection
    {
        public ControlCollection(MyTabControl owner)
            : base(owner)
        { }

        public override void Add(Control value)
        {
            base.Add(value);
            ((MyTabControl)Owner).OnTabAdded(new ControlEventArgs(value));
        }

        public override void Remove(Control value)
        {
            base.Remove(value);
            ((MyTabControl)Owner).OnTabRemoved(new ControlEventArgs(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it would work, unfortunately it's over my head.  Perhaps a slim example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [BeginInvoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) to execute event handler asynchronously. E.g.

```
protected virtual void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>
        {
           if(Controls.Count() == 0)
           {
              ...
           }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: You're right, it should mostly work, but it means that the code will run later than expected instead of earlier than expected, so the same problem may occur in other code that expects that *that* event has finished executing after the tab has been removed. Sometimes that won't be a problem, sometimes it will. When it won't, your answer is a nice idea.